# Javascript output text based on input value

Tags: javascript, forms, if-statement, input, textbox

I'm trying to make a form where you input a number to a textbox and based upon that a text response is put in a textbox.
This is an example of what I have been trying to make work:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function calculate()
            {
                var ph = document.test.ph.value;
                if (ph > 7.45) {
                    var str = "Alkalosis";
                }
                else if (ph < 7.35) {
                    var str = "Acidosis";
                }
                else {
                    var str = "Normal";
                }
                document.test.acidalk.value = str;
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="test">
            pH<input type="textbox" name="ph"><br>
            <input type="submit" value="Calculate"><br>
            <input type="textbox" id="acidalk" >
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

The idea of what I'm trying to achieve is if a number higher than 7.45 is put in the first text box, the button clicked, then the word "Alkalosis" is put in the second text box, but if the number is less than 7.35, the word is "Acidosis" instead.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Have you considered adding jQuery to your HTML document? Doing so would make things like this much more simple.

Comment: I have no problem with adding jQuery, although I have little experience with it and wouldn't know how to code the function I'm attempting to.

Comment: @hellohellosharp - I don't see how jQuery could possibly make this any simpler.  http://i.stack.imgur.com/ssRUr.gif.  Also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/45176/when-is-use-jquery-not-a-valid-answer-to-a-javascript-question

Comment: @aj12 - check my answer for a quick jQuery example.

Comment: @gilly3 - I see your point with the jQUery thing, but still: retrieving and updating form values is obviously more simple with it.

Comment: @hellohellosharp - Accessing form values in plain JS is dead simple: `document.formName.fieldName.value = "new value"`. jQuery's way of reading and writing property values is counterintuitive to developers of any other programming language, or devs who learned JavaScript before learning jQuery. You have direct references to form objects built in to the dom for free. The overhead cost to include jQuery and the cost to query the document with selectors to access built in objects makes no sense. jQuery simplifies *many* things, but not this, unless jQuery is the *only* way you know how to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you're most of the way there. Instead of having the button be a submit button, try

```
<input type="button" onclick="calculate();" value="Calculate" />
```

Comment: Lose the `javascript:` prefix.  It should be just `onclick="calculate()"`.

Comment: Thanks, does just what I was hoping. So close too!

Comment: Mostly semantics, but fine. Just an old habit from years gone.

Answer (score 0):

Base of your code This will be a way to do it:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calculate(){
            var ph = document.getElementById('ph').value;
            if(ph > 7.45){
                var str="Alkalosis";
            }else if(ph < 7.35){
                var str="Acidosis";
            } else{
                var str="Normal";
            }
            document.getElementById('acidalk').value =str;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    pH<input type="textbox" name="ph"><br>
    <button onclick="calculate()">Calculate</button>
    <input type="textbox" id="acidalk" >
</body>
</html>
```

hope helps!

Answer (score 0):

You have the form, you have the function, you just need a way to tie them together.  Do it by assigning `calculate()` as an event handler for the form's `submit` event.  Make sure to `return false` else the form will be submitted and the result of `calculate()` will not be seen.

```
<form name="test" onsubmit="calculate(); return false">
```

[jsfiddle.net/UhJG2](http://jsfiddle.net/UhJG2/)

Binding to the form's `submit` event rather than button's `click` event has the added benefit of calling the function when <kbd>enter</kbd> is pressed.  It also ensures the form is not ever accidentally submitted.

Answer (score 0):

With jQuery:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<body>pH
    <input type="textbox" name="ph" id="ph">
    <br>
    <button id="calculate">Calculate Acid Level</button>
    <br />
    <input type="textbox" id="acidalk" value="" />
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#calculate").click(function () {
        var ph = $("#ph").val();
        if (ph > 7.45) str = "Alkalosis";
        else if (ph < 7.35) var str = "Acidosis";
        else var str = "Normal";

        $("#acidalk").val(str);
    });
</script>
</html>
```